# Liferay Friendly Url redirect to controller method

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay

I tried to create a friendly url policy basing on this tutorial
https://www.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper
But I would like to redirect the url to a function instead of a page (using faces config) because pages need many parameters to be setted on the model before running
in other words I would like to set bean model value before redirect the page
is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume, you want to make some kind of backend logic, and then just redirect user to some page. This is simple example, how I would implement it myself.

```
@ActionMapping(params = {"param1", "param2"})
public void setMethod(@RequestParam String param1, @RequestParam String param1, ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse, Model model){
   //your rocket science logic...

   actionResponse.setRenderParameter("action", "redirectActionName");
}

@RequestMapping(params= {"action=redirectActionName"})
public String view(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse, Model model) {
   //target of redirection
   return "viewPath";
}
```

Then just make correct routes mapping based on article you just quoted. Hope it was helpful somehow.

Comment: It sounds great but I'm not able to have Action or mapping annotation

Comment: Well, idea is pretty the same, no matter if you are using Spring and his annotations or just extends Controller from MVCPortlet. Implement action phase method and then just do redirect to some render phase method. Since I don't have any example using Controller extended from MVCPortlet.class I am not able to paste it here for you.